# azure connected vm remote desktop

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, rdp

I've got two VMs in Azure, the second of which was linked to the first when it was created. I can connect via remote desktop fine to the first VM, but cannot remote desktop to the second nor edit the rdp endpoint. I'm assuming this is something to do with the fact they've both got the same DNS name (the second machine's DNS is auto allocated when you 'link' it to the first). If I use the public IP it connects me to the first VM.

The linking was done so we could load balance between the two but if I can't RDP to the second then it's pretty useless to me.

Any idea how to remote desktop to the second VM or an alternative load balancing (it's an asmx web service we're looking to balance)

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable remote desktop for all VM's within a single cloud service deployment. The external-facing RDP port for each VM will be different, and each will then map to 3389 on their respective vm's. These will be set up as port-forwarded endpoints, meaning not load-balanced.

I'm not sure how you set up your 2nd VM when provisioning, but you should have been able to enable rdp at creation time. If you used the CLI, you'd have something like

```
>azure vm create -c --rdp [port] -n -z size newvmname existingdnsname disk-image-to-use username password
```

By specifying `--rdp`, everything will be automatically set up for you. Just be sure to specify a port different from your first VM's port. If you create the VM through the portal, the port number will be automagically assigned for you.

Comment: Hi David  I used the management portal to set up the second VM. There aren't any rdp endpoints on it and it won't let me set up one for internal 3389

Comment: Correction - have added a new endpoint for internal 3389, it was the external port it didn't like so have used 63389 instead of the one for the first VM - still can't connect.

Comment: Finally figured this out - it was my own firewall blocking the outbound request due to port range restriction - once I used a port the firewall was allowing it worked - many thanks for the responses

Answer (score 1):

Every single VM must have a different public endpoint for RDP. The public endpoint must not be load-balanced. To set the endpoints, select the VM under "virtual machine" and not the cloud service.
When you connect, use the pubblic dns name and the right public port.

Example (works for me):

```
VM1  
   protocol: tcp
   public port: 45623  
   private port: 3389  
   load balanced: NO

VM2
   protocol: tcp
   public port: 15426  
   private port: 3389  
   load balanced: NO
```